# How to pass third party cookies to the respective third party domains?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

I have a domain x and third party domain y. Users will always be on domain x.

There are few cookies are being set after the redirection to third party domain Y for authentication. And we re-direct back the user to domain X. I want to pass these cookies for further requests to third party domain Y.

Tried: I have set the cookie after redirection to domain Y and able to see the set-cookie in the response headers. How to pass these cookies to respective domain Y?

Note: I don't want to pass the domain X cookies to Y, only want to pass the Y domain cookies when calling apis from X domain

Answer (score -1):

Cookies set for a domain are only available to *that* domain.

If you want to communicate the data to a different domain, then use a method other than cookies (such as the body of a POST request).

Comment: I don't want to send the cookies to different domain. Instead I want to send the respective cookies of the domain when I am calling from some other domain?
For eg: X has cookies a and b, Y has cookies c and d.
I want to send cookies c and d, whenever an api call is going to Y from domain X

Comment: Quentin, I rephrased the question and body. I hope you can help me this